How a custom component in MAUI shared images
I'm creating a component using .NET 8 MAUI for my application. In this component, I have some images in SVG format marked as MAUI Image.

I created in the same solution a demo project to test my component. I added the component as a project reference
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\src\PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown.csproj"/>
</ItemGroup>

In the demo project, I can use the images from the component. Then I created the NuGet package for it.
If I create a new project and add the NuGet package, all the images will not be displayed anymore. I thought the component shared the images also with the project.
How can I allow other projects to access and use the images?
Update
I saw on GitHub a possible solution but it is not working for me.
I created a new file called PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown.targets and I added those lines (and all the long list of images)
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <MauiImage Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Images\Flags\f_ad.svg" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Then, I edit the project file (.csproj) and I added the file above
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="PSC.Maui.Components.LanguageDropdown.targets" 
          Pack="True" PackagePath="buildTransitive\" />
</ItemGroup>

and then change this line
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\Flags\f_ad.svg" />

into to this one
<MauiImage Pack="True" PackagePath="buildTransitive\Images\Flags\" 
           Include="Resources\Images\Flags\f_ad.svg" />

When I added the NuGet in a project, I get this error

Unable to find background file: C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\psc.maui.components.languagedropdown\8.0.15\buildTransitive\Images\Flags\f_ad.svg  LanguageDropdownDemo (net8.0-android), LanguageDropdownDemo (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0)    C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\microsoft.maui.resizetizer\8.0.82\buildTransitive\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.After.targets   624

Update/2
I checked the NuGet package itself and I can see this

The package contains only the dll. So, I don't know if it has to have a folder with all the images or the images are embedded in the dll.

This should work as far as I know, are you sure you are packing it correctly?

I thought the same but it doesn't and I don't know why

how are you generating your nuget?

From Azure DevOps, I have a pipeline that I use for all the MAUI components

I reproduced your problem, can you provide the complete code about the image part in the .csproj file?

I created a temporary repository for you here https://github.com/erossini/TempLanguage

@ShuowenHe-MSFT have you seen the repo? What do you think?

According to the Load a local image, you can try to change the svg suffix to png when calling image

@ShuowenHe-MSFT I call the images with .png but they are not found if they are in the NuGet package
